# Force data types when converting xml to json

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using below code piece of code to convert from xml to json,

```
  string xml = @"<root>
                  <person>
                    <name>Alan</name>
                    <rollno>123</rollno>
                  </person>
                </root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Out json string I get is:

```
{
  "root": {
    "person": {
      "name": "Alan",
      "rollno": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is below, with rollno which is number in xml to as number instead of string..

```
{
  "root": {
    "person": {
      "name": "Alan",
      "rollno": 123      <<<<<< to be number and not string<<<<<<
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to force it from xml or any library ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a c# model for your specific object and parse the xml into a json object with those types.

More info here: https://blog.couchbase.com/xml-json-conversion-json-net/